# rasa_core.exceptions.UnsupportedDialogueModelError: Model version: 0.0.0 Instance version: 0.12.3 Minimal compatible version: 0.12.0

Tags: python, rasa-nlu, rasa-core

I wrote the following command for running Rasa Core.

```
>python -m rasa_core.run -d framework/models/dialogue -u framework/models/nlu/default/model_20190121-131223 --endpoints framework/endpoints.yml
```

Running this command is generating the following error.

rasa_core.exceptions.UnsupportedDialogueModelError: The model version is to old to be loaded by this Rasa Core instance. Either retrain the model, or run withan older version. Model version: 0.0.0 Instance version: 0.12.3 Minimal compatible version: 0.12.0

Rasa Core Version: 0.12.3

Rasa NLU Version: 0.13.8

Python 3.6.5

Content of endpoints.yml file

```
action_endpoint:
    url: "http://localhost:5055/webhook/"
```

Since my model version is being showed 0.0.0, do I need to retrain it? If so, then how to retrain it with a higher version?

Comment: Can you check whether the directory with the trained Core model contains a `policy_metadata.json` and check what the value of the entry `rasa_core` is?

Answer (score 0):

python -m rasa_nlu.train -c nlu_model_config.yml --fixed_model_name current --data ./data/nlu.md --path models/ --project nlu

Comment: What does nlu_model_config.yml file contain?

Comment: The error in the question is a Rasa Core error and hence not related to Rasa NLU.